# After changing Document Parameters, NSCocoaErrorDomain 256 opening *new* docs

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist, nsdocument

For the next version of a NSDocument-based app, I am revising the document parameters, that is, the values in Info.plist > CFBundleDocumentTypes and UTExportedTypeDeclarations.  Specifically,  I am changing from a flat NSPersistentDocument to a document package (with the help of [BSManagedDocument](https://github.com/karelia/BSManagedDocument)).

The revised app can create new documents, but they appear in Finder with a generic icon, and when I close such a new document and try to re-open it,  `-[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]`fails, creating an error in NSCocoaErrorDomain with code 256, description *“newDoc.myExtension” could not be handled because MyApp cannot open files of this type*, and failure reason *MyApp cannot open files of this type*.

I understand that there are several significant parameters CFBundleDocumentTypes and UTExportedTypeDeclarations, and these must all be correct or you get this error.  In this case, they are correct.  I've confirmed this by comparing the Info.plist in my built product with the Info.plist of a different but similar app that works.

I've also tried calling `LSRegisterURL()` with `inUpdate = true` from main(), but that did not help.

What might be wrong?  I'm running in macOS 10.12.6, building with macOS 10.13 SDK and Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is in updating the Launch Services database.  I **copied the new application, with the  revised `Info.plist`, into `/Applications`**,  replacing an old version, then launched this copy once.  After these two steps, document icons are now correct when I reopened a Finder window, and upon relaunching my new app, it can now reopen its own new documents without error.

UPDATE: Today (macOS 10.13 Beta 8) I had the same problem, but installing the corrected app into /Applications did not work.  However, this time, rebuilding the Launch Services database by running the following command in Terminal, and then relaunching my app, did work:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain u -domain s -domain l -v`

A side effect of the above is that some apps will have generic icons in the dock and cmd-tab application switcher until relaunched.

I think that either Launch Services much prefers apps in `/Applications` over apps in Xcode's `DerivedData` folder, even if the latter is the only one currently running, or running apps from Xcode's `DerivedData` do not register at all, or both.

It seems from the documentation that calling `LSRegisterURL()` should have had the same effect, but apparently not.